# AFNetworking Uploading Image

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

I've look at a few examples but I think my problem may be with in the PHP. I am trying to upload an image to a server from the iphone using AFNetworking. Here is my obj-c code:

```
    -(IBAction)uploadButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mainImageView.image, 90);
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.THESERVER.com"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/PROJECT/upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *response = [operation responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
        NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

}];

[operation start];
}
```

This is my upload.php:

```
function upload(){
    $uploaddir = '/uploads/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        sendResponse(200, 'Upload Successful');
        return true;
    }
    sendResponse(403, 'Upload Failed');
        return false;

}
```

When I try to upload it fails at

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
```

and returns the 403 / false status code that I set

Comment: most likely a permissions problem. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: since I am doing this through iOS device how can I pass back the error messages? I have a function sendResponse('400',"$errors") that I can use but what do I set $errors to?

Comment: @mkral: i know this is kinda old but I tried implementing a modified version of the upload part of ur code and it didnt work for me
did it work out for u in the end?

p.s im trying to learn ios/objective C

Comment: yea, make sure your destination folder has the correct permissions and that you are writing it in the correct destination

Comment: WARNING ROOKIE QUESTION: Which files do I need to import to `viewcontroller.m` ? I have `#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"` what else? I am getting an error for `AFHTTPClient`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a silly mistake...

in php i needed

```
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
```

instead of

```
$uploaddir = '/uploads/';
```

Comment: hey man, I used your code but I got "response: [(null)]", could you help me with it? thanx

Comment: that most likely means you are getting an error on your web-service or it is not returning any JSON

Comment: Is it possible to send me the upload part of your code? I've been looking for a working example for the past two days. Thanx

Comment: As in the php part of the code? I can't send you the code (as I no longer work for that company and dont have access) but I can help you if you have some questions. Do you have any code?

Comment: Thanx man, the PHP part is ok, I tested it using html and it works fine, my problem is it doesn't upload it from objective c part.

Comment: It's most likely that you aren't passing anything back to the iPhone if you're using the code above. Specifically `sendResponse(200, 'Upload Successful');` if instead you change it to `echo "Success"` or `echo "failure"`  Does the `response: null` change? Did you check if the file is being uploaded into the directory you specified? Also check the directory permissons so they are set to write

Comment: Hi, I have also tested your code an got the same problem. I got response 200 but [null] and the image didn't upload. I have checked the php code from an html and it worked. Can you help?