# How to upload image to a server

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload

I use these code in ios to upload my image

It almost the same with another code on the `Internet`

```
NSData *uploadImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1) ;
NSString *uploadURL = @"http://...../jeff.php" ;

NSMutableURLRequest *uploadRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[uploadRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uploadURL]] ;
[uploadRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"] ;

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=%@",boundary];
[uploadRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:uploadImage]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[uploadRequest setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:uploadRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"echo：%@",returnString);
```

My PHP is

```
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
    echo "yes \r\n";
}
else
{
    echo "NO \r\n";
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    echo "http://...../uploads/{$file}";
}
```

But it's not working

My upload folder is /var/www/uploads

Comment: any error is prompted ? define `not working`

Comment: I would strongly recommend doing it with AFNetworking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888167/afnetworking-uploading-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FOR POST METHOD READ MY OWN ANSWER FROM.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377212/get-the-password-from-the-webservices-url-and-access-through-that-password/15377242#15377242)

And Use This code For image posting.

```
NSString  *imgPath = fullPathOfYourImage;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imgPath])
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                                                        
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"YourImageName.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                                                                                               ^..YourImageName….^

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
```

Comment: Composing a multipart form data message is quite error prone. Your answer is not correct in some important details: Your boundaries are not correct, and  image data should have a corresponding MIME type - application/octet-stream isn't appropriate.

Comment: how to upload multiple image files to server

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method, I have tested it and is working

The PHP

```
<?php
$image = $_REQUEST['image'];

$imageFileName = "miImage.jpg";

$binary = base64_decode($image);
$file = fopen($imageFileName, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo "Upload completed with success";
?>
```

In YourViewController.h file

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
    NSURLConnection *serverConnection;
    NSMutableData *returnData;
}
```

Copy and paste this method in YourViewController.m file

```
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*) theData {
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Now this are the lines of code to send the image

```
NSURL *sendURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/yourphp.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *sendRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sendURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

[sendRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[sendRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0);

NSString *encodedString = [[self base64forData:imageData] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

stringBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"image=%@", encodedString];

[sendRequest setHTTPBody:[stringBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

serverConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:sendRequest delegate:self];

[serverConnection start];
```

Last thing is to set the delegate methods of the server connection

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    returnData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [returnData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);

    if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"Upload completed with success"]) {

        /* Do something on success */

    } else {

        /* Do something if not succeeded */

    }
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    /* Do something in fail */
}
```